# returned results from promise.all() does not capture scoped variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am having issue with capturing each id from queryArray and storing it with the return promise results.

```
getSavedQueries: function(req, res) {
    SPromise.then(function(client) {
      const SavedQuery = client.Reports;
      var queryArray = req.query.queryArray; // ['123', '234', '456']
      var payloadObj = {};
      var actions = lo.map(queryArray, function(id) {
        var queryID = Number(id);
        *payloadObj['ID'] = queryID;* <--- not sure where to put this
        return SavedQuery.findOne(queryID).then(function(result){
          payloadObj['query'] = result;
          return payloadObj
        });
      });
      return Promise.all(actions);
    }).then(function(result){
      return res.json(result)
    });
  }
```

my res.json(result) returns with the last item on the array for all three objects:

```
[ {ID: 456, query: ...}, 
  {ID: 456, query: ...}, 
  {ID: 456, query: ...}]
```

Instead of :

```
  [ {ID: 123, query: ...}, 
    {ID: 234, query: ...}, 
    {ID: 456, query: ...}]
```

Comment: You keep using the same `payloadObj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `payloadObj` is defined outside of the map callback. Because of this, the same object is being mutated during the map callback and returned from the `then` method called on the promise created in the map callback, so that the array passed to `Promise.all` contains 3 promises which will all resolve to the *same object*, whose `ID` property will be the last ID in the array (since this map callback is called last) and whose `query` property will be the result of the last request that succeeds (probably, but not necessarily, the last request).